# How can a web part know it's EditorPart is open

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, sharepoint-api

I've created a web part with a custom editor part.
Now I want to make changes in the behaviour of the web part if the editor part is open.

I can almost get it to work by setting a flag in the CreateEditorParts() method except that also fires when the user clicks "OK", "Apply" or "Cancel". The page will render without the editor part open but the web part still executes the CreateEditorParts method.

I haven't been able to find a property on the System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts.WebPart class that would indicate this, which seems like so obviously where it should be ;)

.. is there a way?

Answer (score 2):

You could check to see if the page is in edit mode using the following:

```
 WebPartManager wpm = WebPartManager.GetCurrentWebPartManager(Page);
 if (wpm.DisplayMode == WebPartManager.EditDisplayMode)
 {
      //Page is in edit mode
 }
```

I haven't tested this, but you could do this check in CreateEditorParts() and the code should only execute when the editorpart is open.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested it but perhaps checking the visibility of the EditorPart itself might be an option.

Answer (score 0):

In case it might be helpful to others:

There are several *points* where your WebPart might figure out that its EditorPart is being shown. One of those might fit in your scenario:

In WebPart:

- [IWebEditable.CreateEditorParts](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.webparts.iwebeditable.createeditorparts.aspx): "[...] The WebPartManager control takes the collection and creates instances of all the EditorPart controls **whenever the server control enters edit mode**."
- [WebPart.OnEditModeChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.webparts.webpart.oneditmodechanged.aspx): check if both WebPartManager.DisplayMode is EditDisplayMode and WebPartManager.SelectedWebPart is your WebPart. Please note that, based on my experience, that was invoked only upon entering edit mode, not upon leaving it.
- [WebPartManager.DisplayModeChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.webparts.webpartmanager.displaymodechanged.aspx): perform same checks as previous one. Although based on my experience, that was never invoked.

In EditorPart:

- [EditorPart.SyncChanges](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.webparts.editorpart.syncchanges.aspx): "[...] Another case where the SyncChanges method is called is when a WebPart control is entering edit mode."
- One of the EditorPart life-cycle methods (e.g. OnInit /OnLoad). The EditorPart has anyway a reference to the *parent* WebPart by means of [EditorPart.WebPartToEdit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.webparts.editorpart.webparttoedit.aspx) property.